# How to download latest patch to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Many users reported problem with debugging in Visual Studio after Update 2, guys from Visual Studio fix this issue 11/4/2016 in version 14.025126.03. Whitch is nice!

But, how can I download this patch? It's 10 days!

Edit: Guys from VS team send email after voting in "Report a Problem...", but they send it with typo, 14.025126.03 should be **14.0.25126.03**, as Kanavos refer; so I wasn't able to find it on Google and it's my source of confuse. 
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695655.aspx) is link to MSDN with update.

[image: Email]

Comment: What bug? What fix? Just because *someone* thinks there is a bug, it doesn't mean that there actually is one. Or that your case is the same as theirs. Post the relevant link

Comment: After fixing your version number, the download pages appear as the first two results in a google search. I would *not* install this though, unless I *did* encounter of the bugs it fixes

Comment: This version 14.025126.03 is what Microsoft send me in automatic email reply; so if they send wrong version don't be surprised, that I'm not able to find it.

Comment: You typed it wrong. There should be a dot after 0. Google it again. Automated emails though contain links to the actual download files and KB articles. That's how I found the page

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/B/2FBFF8C2-CCC4-4B6B-BF50-08DCFA248D3D/vs14-kb3151378.exe, from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695655.aspx